# android, phonegap 2.9 - inappbrowser behavior

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

what I have to do is to display something using the inappbrowser plugin.

I use this code to test:

```
iaRef = window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank', 'location=yes');
iaRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { 
    console.log("stopped!");
    iaRef.executeScript({
      code: 'console.log("inappbrowser"); var div = document.body.children[0]; var span = document.createElement("div"); span.innerHTML = "new content!!!"; div.insertBefore(span, div.firstChild);'
      }, 
      function(data) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); }
    );
    iaRef.insertCSS({ code: "body { background: green; }"}, function() { console.log("CSS altered");});
});
```

Everything works fine for a lot of websites, even the ones that have redirects (for example repubblica.it). Some of them don't work, for example google.com.
I can see all the correct log lines (`'loadstart'` and `'loadstop'` events) but the final result is NOT changed.

**EDIT:** If I run the same javascript in a web console, everything's fine.

In the configuration file I have `<access origin="*" />` if it's still used by inappbrowser (hard to understand from the documentation, it seems not).

I cannot risk to lack the support of some websites. Is there any solution to this problem, or even another plugin to accomplish this task?

Thanks

Comment: Could you just add a screenshot to the result and also log lines?